# Kudan: Is it possible to call a function when a marker is detected?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, kudan

I am using Kudan AR framework https://www.kudan.eu/ to develop iPhone app on Xcode 7.3.1.

I am able to reproduce the basic like how to setup model and tracker. When a marker is detected in an ARCameraViewController, an armodel successfully appears in the camera view.

My situation is: I want to call a function when a marker is detected in ARCameraViewController. The function may be print("hello") or download something.

How may we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use:

```
- (void)addTrackingEventTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forEvent:(ARImageTrackableEvents)event;
```

e.g.

```
[trackable addTrackingEventTarget:self action:@selector(imageDetected:) forEvent:ARImageTrackableEventDetected];
```

You can find a bit more documentation about this in Kudan's API docs https://wiki.kudan.eu/apidocs/iOSDocs/db/de1/interface_a_r_image_trackable.html#ae5329511da8f0b137e2d472e52c22e95